# Understanding to errors in /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, logs

Recently I've been checking my log and found two weird errors which I don't understand.

The first one:

`May 22 08:11:00 localhost dbus: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.25" (uid=42 pid=2827 comm="gnome-power-manager) interface="org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.LaptopPanel" member="GetBrightness" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination=":1.7" (uid=0 pid=2155 comm="hald))q`

The second one (this one repeats a lot):

`May 22 16:14:55 localhost NetworkManager[1991]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan: (6) Remote Exception invoking org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority.CheckAuthorization() on /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority at name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Remote Exception invoking org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixUser() on / at name org.freedesktop.DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.49': no such name`

Does anyone know what those mean?

Comment: Are these errors accompanied by any unusual behavior?

Comment: No. I'm just curious.

Comment: Does this computer have wifi? What's the distro?

Comment: Yes, it has wifi and it's Centos 6.

Comment: Can you provide us some screenshots of your NetworkManager setup? Sounds like you have some additional wifi networks configured that aren't either correct or their configs are hosed. Shows you how to get at it if you're not sure: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Interacting_with_NetworkManager.html